# What is the necessary and sufficient condition for this Cartesian product to be a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $m_1$, $m_2$, $\ldots$, $m_n$ be positive integers, and let $Z_{m_i}$ denote the group $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, m_{i}-1\}$ under addition modulo $m_i$, for each $i = 1,2, \ldots, n$.

Then what is the necessary and sufficient condition for the Cartesian product $\Pi_{i=1}^n Z_{m_i}$ to be cyclic?

Comment: $(m_1,\ldots,m_n)=1$

Comment: @AlexYoucis No, the requirement is that they are pairwise coprime, not that there is no common factor among them all.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Of course. That was a stupid mistake.

Comment: But how to prove this in case of more than two factors?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\mathbb{Z}_n\times\mathbb{Z}_m\cong\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ if and only if $m$ and $n$ share no prime factors.

Comment: Jared, yes, but how to give the proof for the result for more than two factors? It is that any two of the positive integers are relatively prime in pairs. However I'm not sure how to give a proof.